# How can I get samba users from the same group to edit each others files?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, samba

I'm setting up my first linux fileserver for Windows clients and am having some problems properly setting up the shares. I have a shared folder via Samba where multiple users (who are organized by group) should have permissions of rwxrwx--- (0770). But when user "joe" creates a folder and a file within it, user "jane" cannot move those files out or create files there.
Ubuntu 12.04 3.2.0-30-generic
Samba version 3.6.3

from /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[sharename]
path = /srv/samba/sharename
; browseable = yes
writeable = yes
valid users = @somegroup
force group = somegroup
create mode = 0770
force create mask - 0770
directory mode = 0770
force directory mode = 0770
inherit permissions = yes
vfs object = recycle
recycle:repository = RecycleBin
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:exclude = *.tmp, *.bak
```

How can I make it so that members of the same security group can edit each other's work?
I've already set the initial permissions to be:
drwxrwx--- 7 root somegroup 4096 Jan 01 12:00 sharename
by issuing:

```
sudo chmod 0770 -R /srv/samba/sharename
```

and then:

```
sudo chgrp somegroup -R /srv/samba/sharename
```

I'd still like to know who owns each file and who edited the file last, but want members of the same group edit each other's work.
Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. I'm trying to keep this small business from buying a Windows domain controller if possible.

Comment: You shouldn't use inherit permissions with create mode/directory mode, as it overrides their behavior. That said your configuration should work if "jane" is a member of somegroup.

Comment: Can you verify the unix permissions for the files created by "joe"?